# Why am I getting an empty element in my array when using useDelimiter

Tags: java

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
Event=LightOn,time=2000
Event=WaterOff,time=10000
Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
Event=WaterOn,time=6000
Event=LightOff,time=4000
Event=Terminate,time=20000
Event=FansOn,time=7000
Event=FansOff,time=8000
```

I have a method like this:

```
public void extractDataIntoArray() {
    array = new ArrayList<String>();    
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        s.useDelimiter("(,.*)|[^0-9]+");
        array.add(s.next());
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

I want to return only the time values such as "0", "2000", and so on. On the fifth line of the text file, I want to completely ignore "rings=5". Also, the value for "rings=" will not always be 5, it changes but I still want to ignore it. Using the regex above I was able to get this output:

> [0, 2000, 10000, 12000, 9000, , 6000, 4000, 20000, 7000, 8000]

Notice that in the 6th position of the array there is an empty value. What can I add to my delimiter to remove this empty value?

Comment: Your delimiter matches the rings. Maybe it should be something like `time=...`

Comment: Don't I want the delimiter to match the rings so it is removed ?

Comment: I want to ignore "rings=5" or any other number for example "rings=23"

Comment: Is it always going to be "rings" that you want to ignore?

Comment: yes, for any text file I scan i want to ignore "rings=(whatever number it may be)"

Comment: I've been able to ignore it as shown in my output example but it still places an empty token in the array, which is what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: Yes, I know. Will it be enough for you if you just don't add empty strings to your array?

Comment: That will work. So just an if statement before I add it to the array?

Comment: Yes, I'll put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it should be enough to just not add empty strings to the array as you're already ignoring the "ring=X" part

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    s.useDelimiter("(,.*)|[^0-9]+");
    String next = s.next();
    if (next.length() > 0)
        array.add(next);
    System.out.println(array);
}
```